# Neo4j Load Json using Apoc.load.Json in java

Tags: java, json, stored-procedures, neo4j, cypher

I want to load my Json file into neo4j server using Apoc procedure, for that I used following query...

```
call apoc.load.json("file:///training.json") yield value Return value
```

but it is showing me the error

> "Failed to invoke procedure `apoc.load.json`: Caused by:
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't read url file:///training.json as
>   json: \training.json (The system cannot find the file specified)".

Expected behaviour is Specified json file is to be loaded in to neo4j server.

**problem is:** It is not at all recognizing the file That is specified in URL.

please help me out to resolve this error

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow :-) please post a [mcve] and look at [ask]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
call apoc.load.json("file:///training.json") yield value Return value
```

for the above query the URL is specified as `"file:///training.json"`. Instaed of this Specify full path name in URL.

for eg: I put my json file named `"training.json"` in following specified path

> C:\Users\TEMP.DESKTOP9FCLQ6J.002\Documents\Neo4j\default.graphdb\import\training.json

so in query specify the above full path name. Instead of C:// specify the protocol name file:///

The correct answer is:

```
call apoc.load.json("file:///Users\\TEMP.DESKTOP-9FCLQ6J.002\\Documents\\Neo4j\\default.graphdb\\import\\test.json") yield value 
Return value.
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For the above call `apoc.load.json`, I'd use a backslash to get it working, on a Windows 10 PC:

```
WITH "file:///Users/mukundan/Documents/Neo4j/default.graphdb/import/sudish-graph_working1.json" 
AS url
CALL apoc.load.json(url) 
YIELD value
```